# I want to create paging on my content managed site

Tags: php, codeigniter, managed

I'm trying to load a blog type page, I load the entries from my database with this controller

```
    public function blog($page){
    $this->load->model("model_get");
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $counter = $this->model_get->getBlogcount();

    for($counter; $counter > 0; $counter --){
        $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getBlog($counter);
        $this->load->view("content_blog", $data);
        }
    }

    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}
```

and this model

```
    function getBlogcount(){
        $result = $this->db->count_all("blog");

        return $result;
    }
```

I count the entries in the database where I call them out by their ID. But now I'm trying to create multiple pages that expand automatically everytime I enter a new entry. So lets say I have 27 entries, and want to have no more than 5 entries on a single page, how do I make it so that it creates the necessary 6 pages to show them without loading the other 3 empty entries and stuff.
I'm new to codeigniter and have always worked with ASP .NET, any help would be helpfull.
Thanks in advance!

p.s. english isn't my first language

Comment: are you looking for pagination? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I'm looking for! But how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter have his own pagination Class. Take a look here : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

You can try this firstly and adapt to your project :

```
public function blog($page = 0)
{
   $this->load->library('pagination');
   $this->load->helper('url');

   $config['base_url'] = base_url('blog/'. $page);
   $config['total_rows'] = $this->model_get->getBlogcount();
   $config['per_page'] = 5;

   $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

   $data['results'] = $this->model_get->getBlog($config['per_page'], $page);
   $this->load->view("content_blog", $data);
}
```

Edit your "getBlog" function model to get results with limit clause, like this :

```
function getBlog($limit, $start)
{
    $results = $this->db->limit($limit, $start)->get('your_blog_table');

    if ($results) 
    {
        return $results->result();
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

And use in your view this code to create your pagination links :

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with the limit clause on my database function? So far thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't read your code here, but you call initialize with $config variable before you define $config variable... Please go read some basic tutorials by typing "codeigniter pagination" in Google.

Comment: I'm awefully sorry, seems like I wasn't really awake, I only get one error now, and it loads 1 result, but nothing else. And it still gives an undefined variable on the $data in the base_url config. I also use $data to load all the content on all of my pages, and in my view I use a foreach($results as $row)

Comment: Yes my mistake, I think I have wrote the correct way.

Comment: I get 0 errors, but I still only see 1 entry. Also, I don't see the other links from the "<p><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></p>" code